# Как добавить прокрутки в DIV плавности? Помогите дописать скрипт

Tags: jquery

Имею такой код.

```js
  $.ajax({
      url: "modul/im/messsages/load_chat.php?chat=<?=$cid?>",
      timeout: 10000,
      type: "POST",
      data: {id: id},
      success: function(data){
          if(data==1) {

          } else {
              $(".scrolcontent").append(data);
              $(".scrolcontent").scrollTop($(".scrolcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
          }
      }
  });
```

```html
<div class="scrolcontent"></div>
```

Сам JS подтягивает контент в DIV с классом `scrolcontent` у самого дива прописана в стилях прокрутка. Суть во в чем. Код работает но прокрутка быстрая, а хочется сделать плавно.

За прокрутку отвечает вот этот кусок скрипта.

```
$(".scrolcontent").scrollTop($(".scrolcontent")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```js
  $.ajax({
      url: "modul/im/messsages/load_chat.php?chat=<?=$cid?>",
      timeout: 10000,
      type: "POST",
      data: {id: id},
      success: function(data){
          if(data==1) {

          } else {
              $(".scrolcontent").append(data);
              var scrolPx = $(".scrolcontent")[0].scrollHeight;
              $(".scrolcontent").animate({scrollTop: scrolPx }, 800);
          }
      }
  });
```